# How to add custom action in customer address grid in backend magento2

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.4

I have added a custom field in customer_address_entity and want to change it's field value on custom button's click which should be in customer edit form.

Action is working properly but there is an issue when we field gets updated then updated data doesn't display in grid by action.

Comment: Do you want radio button in frontend side customer edit page?

Comment: no, in address edit form which is under customer view's tab.